# Create word-count application that accounts for multiple lines of text in an input file

Tags: java, while-loop

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader( "/input5.txt"));
```

> input5.txt is the text file from which I read the input.

```
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new FileReader "/input5.txt"));
    int wordcount = 0;//counter

    int i = 0;//each character of input
    boolean hasChar = true;//flag for has Character
    while (in.hasNextLine()) { // while input exists
        String a = in.nextLine();//get next line
        while (i < a.length()) {// get each char

            if (a.charAt(i) == ' ') {// blank space does not count in word count
                hasChar = false;
            }// does not work
            else {

                wordcount++;// count words
            }
            i++;//get each char
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The word count is " + wordcount);// print wordcount
    System.out.println("");
    String line;// echo print the input file
    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Echo print of the file: " + line);
    }
    in.close();

}
```

That's my code.

The Input file includes this

Aiwegfu24r;q0912j

129puehilhwueildgyuol

The second line of code is not counted for in the word count. How may I fix this with while loops only?

Please do not give me the answer but rather guide me.

Comment: When you say "it is not counted", what exactly do you mean? What output do you get when you run your program?

Comment: You want the character count here. Right??

Comment: Read the documentation to `Scanner.next()`. It should provide you with an easier solution.

Comment: You have to reset `i` after `while` loop at first. Also new lines are ignored. You can just read a file into one String and split it with pattern

Comment: @nash_ag, no I do not want the character count but rather the word count.

Comment: If you move the declaration of `i` inside your `while` loop, you will get the correct number (i won't tell you why, since you did not want the answer :)). 
Also, note, that, as others have pointed out, you are counting (non-space) characters, rather than words. Not sure if that was the intent. 
And also, the way you are counting them, the result is going to be larger than you expected by 2 (again, won't say why, but you can find the answer by studying the docs for Scanner.nextLine).
If you want the word count rather than character count, Scanner.next() is your friend as suggested above.

Comment: As answered below you can use split rather than the loop.

Comment: what does scanner.next do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not resetting the value of i when you read the new line. And that's the reason why during next line you are not entering the inner while loop.

So a hint would be, your while loop should be resetting i value with something like:

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    i = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way might be to split the line based on space:

```
String[] a = in.nextLine().split("\\s+");//get next line
wordCount += a.length();
```